# awk: print one line per field-1 value (distinct) where difference "field-2 - field-3" is minimum

Tags: awk

I want to distinct print the lines where diff is minimum. (diff=$2-$3)

The input file is:

```
c1,5,2         <-- diff=3
c1,5,3         <-- diff=2
c1,5,1         <-- diff=4
c2,8,3         <-- diff=5
c2,8,4         <-- diff=4
```

The expected output is:

```
c1,5,3  
c2,8,4
```

How can I do this with Awk (e.g. with a one-liner)?

---

In other words, for each first field value (c1, c2), I want to print a single line with that first field value, chosen for the minimal diff between the second and third fields.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, it's not unclear at all.  The two lines you cite have **different** first fields.  Read the question title again.  I've made an edit to make it clearer, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enjoy ***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F, '{ diff=$2-$3; if(a[$1]>diff || !a[$1]) { a[$1]=diff; b[$1]=$2 FS $3 } }
         END{ for(i in a) print i,b[i] }' OFS=',' yourfile
```

The output:

```
c1,5,3
c2,8,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Two-pass Awk command, fairly dirty:

```
awk -F, 'FNR == NR {diff[NR] = $2-$3;
         if (!($1 in minline) || diff[NR] < diff[minline[$1]]) {
           minline[$1]=NR}; next}
         FNR == 1 {for (a in minline) {p[minline[a]]}}
         FNR in p' file.csv file.csv
```

For interest, here is how to do this using SQL (done in Postgres, to be specific):

```
vagrant=# \d quick 
   Table "pg_temp_2.quick"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 f1     | text    | 
 f2     | integer | 
 f3     | integer | 

vagrant=# select * from quick;
 f1 | f2 | f3 
----+----+----
 c1 |  5 |  2
 c1 |  5 |  3
 c1 |  5 |  1
 c2 |  8 |  3
 c2 |  8 |  4
(5 rows)

vagrant=# select f1, f2, f3 from (select *, rank() over (partition by f1 order by f2 - f3) from quick) as x where rank = 1;
 f1 | f2 | f3 
----+----+----
 c1 |  5 |  3
 c2 |  8 |  4
(2 rows)

vagrant=#
```

---

Comment: Both proposals fit the purpose; thank you both!